# SQL - returning value if match or first item of list if not

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need a SQL Query to return a phone number if it matches the phone number supplied, or return the first value of a list of phone numbers ordered by the most recent.

Say the client has 3 phone numbers:

```
ID   ClientID   Number          Order
1    1          07123123123     2
2    1          07321321321     3
3    1          07111111111     1
```

If the phone number supplied in the query was 07321321321, then it would return 07321321321. If the phone number supplied didn't match any of the numbers or was black, it would return the top 1 number, ordered by the Order column.

Is there an obvious way of doing this, or getting the following SQL to work?

```
SELECT TOP 1 Number 
FROM ClientPhoneNumbers cpn 
WHERE cpn.ClientId = clientlist.ClientId 
ORDER BY (Number = <phonenumbersupplied>), cpn.[Order]) AS [PhoneNumber]
```

Using SQL-Server

Thanks!

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: Now Supplied...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I would do:

```
select top (1) number
from ((select @number, 1 as ord
       from ClientPhoneNumbers
       where number = @number
      ) union all
      (select top (1) number, 2
       from ClientPhoneNumbers
       order by order
      )
     ) cp
order by ord;
```

You can also do this as:

```
select top (1) cpn.number
from ClientPhoneNumbers cpn
order by (case when cpn.number = @number then 1 else 2 end),
         cpn.order;
```

Comment: That second code block is exactly what I needed - thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can use `value` constructor with `JOIN`  :

```
select top 1 cpn.number
from ClientPhoneNumbers cpn left join ( 
            values ('07321321321') 
     ) tt (number) 
     on tt.number = cpn.number
order by (case when tt.number is not null then 0 else cpn.[order] end);
```